# How to call angularjs service repeatedly from controller to update the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to update my view for every second based on my server response. I'm working with real time data display application. I need to send request to server for every second and get the response and display into my view. Currently i'm using jquery and ajax for request and response.

Just now i'm trying to use angularjs and used bellow code to get response from server,

```
'use strict';

angular.module('liverate', ['dataServices']);

angular.module('dataServices', []).
service('Data', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var my_Date = new Date();
    var rates = {};
     var urlBase = BASE_URL+"api/apirate.php"+"?nocache=" + my_Date.getUTCSeconds();

     this.getRates = function () {
        $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: urlBase,
              //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
              success: function(data){
                   console.log(data);
                   rates = data;
              },
              error : function(statusCode,error) {
                  console.log(error);
              }
            });
        return rates;
     };
}]);

function LiverateController($scope, $timeout, Data) {
    $scope.data = [];
    var rates = {};
    (function tick() {
        $scope.data = Data.getRates(function(){
            $timeout(tick, 1000);
        });
    })();

    And also tried bellow method

    $scope.callAtTimeout = function() {
        console.log(Data.getRates());
    }

    $timeout( function(){ $scope.callAtTimeout(); }, 1000);

};
```

But this didn't work for me. Just it call single time.How i need to use this. Please any one help me.

Comment: For a real time application a WebSocket should be used. At the very least you should use long polling in a service, that updates your model. Your controller should consume the model and allow angular binding to update the view when the model changes. The controller should be dumb, not do any polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not quite understanding how `$http`/promises are used. You need to return the promise that `$http` returns back to the calling function, or a derived promise from that one, such as in the below code:

```
angular.module('dataServices', []).
service('Data', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
  var my_Date = new Date();
  var rates = {};
  var urlBase = BASE_URL+"api/apirate.php"+"?nocache=" + my_Date.getUTCSeconds();

  this.getRates = function () {
    return $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: urlBase,
    }).then(function(results) {
       console.log(results);
       return results.data;
    }, function(error) {
       console.log(error);
       return $q.reject(error);
    });
  };
}]);

function LiverateController($scope, $timeout, Data) {
   $scope.data = [];
   var rates = {};
   (function tick() {
     Data.getRates().then(function(data){
       $scope.data = data;
     })['finally'](function() {
       $timeout(tick, 1000);
     });
   })();
};
```

Also

- I would lean towards using `$timeout` over `$interval`, as as naive use of `$interval` could end up hammering the server in case it's a bit slow
- The call to `$timeout` is actually in a `finally` callback, to run in case of both success and failure of the request.

Comment: Really too thanks. I was struggling long time. It's help me lot. Working as i'm expecting.